# Remove all zeroes except in numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have to remove all the zeroes in a string, but I have to keep the zeroes in numbers.

The strings I receive are in a format similar to "zeroes-letter-zeroes-number", without the '-' and the numbers are always integers. A few examples:

```
"0A055" -> "A55"
"0A050" -> "A50"
"0A500" -> "A500"
"0A0505" -> "A505"
"0055" -> "55"
"0505" -> "505"
"0050" -> "50"
```

I know I can iterate trough the characters in the string and set a flag when I encounter a letter or a number different from 0, but I think that using a RegEx would nicer. The RegEx would also be more helpful if I'll have to use this algorithm in the database.

I tried something like this but I don't get the results that I want:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[0*([a-zA-Z]*)0*([1-9]*)]");
string result = r.Replace(input, "");
```

I'm not so good in writing RegEx-es so please help me if you can.

Comment: So, you mean decimal number? Is a decimal point part of a number?

Comment: @Mentoliptus, is it the case (as in your examples) that there is either 1 or 0 letters? i.e. you won't see 0ABC0123? Also, can there be more than one zero in each location? (Just to clarify.)

Comment: @Jodrell, i edited and specified there are no decimal numbers

Comment: @AAT, for now I receive strings with only 1 letter, but this could change in the future

Comment: Both LikeH's and Brad Christie's answers work, can I mark both as answers? Thank you guys for being so quick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not convinced that a regex is the best way to approach this, but this one works with all your test cases:

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(dirty, @"(?<!\d)0+|0+(?!\d|$)", "");
```

Comment: I don't like the RegEx approach, but I think I'll have to transfer this algorithm in SQL so I hope to use the same RegEx twice.

Comment: I tested this on nregex.com and it strips the final zeros as well, so 0A500 becomes A5.  is this a bug on there behalf?

Comment: @Sam: Maybe, or maybe just a difference between the JavaScript and .NET implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your pattern correctly, [the following should work](http://www.ideone.com/BOl75).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                List<String> samples = new List<String>(new[]{
                        "0A055","0A050","0A500","0A0505","0055","0505","0050"
                });

                String re = @"^0*([A-Z]*)0*([1-9]\d*)$";

                // iterate over all results
                samples.ForEach(n => {
                        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" -> \"{1}\"",
                                n,
                                Regex.Replace(n, re, "$1$2")
                        );
                });
        }
}
```

With the following output:

```
"0A055" -> "A55"
"0A050" -> "A50"
"0A500" -> "A500"
"0A0505" -> "A505"
"0055" -> "55"
"0505" -> "505"
"0050" -> "50"
```

Basically use the pattern to negate all 0s that don't matter, and use the regex replace grouping to re-concatenate the "meaningful" numbers (and letters when present).

Answer (score 1):

Like some of the others I'm not sure regex is the best idea here, but this works with the test cases:

```
0+(?=[0-9].)|0(?=[a-zA-z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])0+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to only have one letter, you can split the string in two halves on that letter.

On the left part, trim all zeros.

On the right part, convert it to a number, this will drop all leading zeros or you could use TrimStart.

Comment: There are cases with no letters

Comment: Good idea for now, but I don't generate the strings and the format could change. I already receive strings with more than 1 letter but those don't have zeroes for now.

Answer (score 0):

To do a replace with regex will be much harder than extracting the value you want. So try match the string using a simple regex like below

```
0*(?<letter>[A-Z])0*(?<number>\d*)
```

Your match result will then contain two groups, letter and number. Take the value of the two group and append them and you will get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl answer for what it's worth

```
s/0*([a-zA-Z]*)0*([1-9]+0*)/$1$2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how regex is implemented in .net, so I'll let you write the proper code with the toys in [System.Text.Regularexpressions.Regex (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Either way, this pattern should work (in pseudo-code):

```
Replace "(0*)(.+)" by "$2"
```

`0*` means zero or more 0

`.+` means any character except end of line

`$2` represents the second set of brackets (so we're simply discarding the (`0*`) part of the string).